# Making 100% height website, with min-height: 100%;, still not showing when I scroll

Tags: css, background, scroll, height, min

I'm adapting this - quintadobode.thetwilightwalkers.com - html template, and when I scroll (on one of the pages with content, like o projecto, etc.) there's no background. I'm using an .expandheight class, with min-height: 100%;, and that still happens. It's driving me nuts, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `height: 100%` set on your `main` element.  It works fine for me if you remove this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really tested your CSS, but if you remove the `height:100%` from your #main block styles, the background will go all the way down for pages like "O Projecto", does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `min-height:100%` on `html` and `body` as well.